# How to do query on json array field

Tags: sql-server-2016

How to do query on json array field.

my sql table field is  personal data and the sample data is below

```
[{"Name":"A","Age":"12"},
{"Name":"B","Age":"22"},
{"Name":"C","Age":"22"}]
```

So the query needed is some thing like Name=A

Comment: Please describe your expected output

Answer (score 0):

This should put the JSON in a format that you can query normally:

```
select 
 SUBSTRING([name], CHARINDEX(':', [name]) + 1, 8000) as [name]
,SUBSTRING([age], CHARINDEX(':', [age]) + 1, 8000) as [name]

from
(select
 SUBSTRING(value, 1, CHARINDEX(',', value) - 1) AS [name]
,SUBSTRING(value, CHARINDEX(':',value)+3,CHARINDEX(',',value)-1) as [age]

from
(select replace(replace(replace(replace(strTest, '[', ''), '}', ''), ']', ''), '"', '') as strMod
from [dbo].[tblTest]
) as a

cross apply string_split(strMod, '{')
where value <> ''
) as b
```